# C# How to access a shared outlook/exchange mailbox programmatically from a C# console application to move emails from inbox to another folder

Tags: c#, outlook, office-automation

I need to write a console application that essentially will:

1. Access a group/shared mailbox's inbox.
2. Select all emails older than n minutes.
3. Move the selected emails to another folder "AgedEmails".

So far the program I wrote works well connecting to my email account, even not passing credentials.
The challenge is to access the shared emailbox not mine.  The program will run in a server on a frequency set in Windows task scheduler.  I have read many postings where the problem is the same I have, but could not find a solution that works.
I have tried the nameSpace.Logon method but it always connects to my employee's email account.

These are the many ways I tried to login to the shared email account (none work):
outlookNameSpace.Logon("mailboxname@company.com", "", true, true);
outlookNameSpace.Logon("mailboxname@company.com", "theRealPassword");,
and this is how I try to get a handle into the inbox:
inboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.Folders["mailboxname@company.com"].Folders["Inbox"];

I am looking for some one to put me in the right direction to achieve the goal.  This application will run unattended.

Thanks in advance for your support.  Here is the source code:

```
static async Task MoveEmailsAsync()
{
 StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(path, append: true);
 Application outLookApplication = null;
 NameSpace outlookNameSpace = null;
 MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
 MAPIFolder sourceFolder = null;
 MAPIFolder testFolder = null;
 Items mailItems = null;

 string sSourceFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceFolder"];
 string destinationFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationFolder"];

 try
 {
   int minutesAged = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesAged"]);
   DateTime age = DateTime.Now;
   outLookApplication = new Application();
   outlookNameSpace = outLookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
   inboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
   sourceFolder = inboxFolder.Folders[sSourceFolder.ToString()];
   testFolder = inboxFolder.Folders[destinationFolder.ToString()];
   mailItems = sourceFolder.Items;
   string from = null;
   string subject = null;
   int counter = mailItems.Count;
   int i = 0;
   for (int k = counter; k >= 1; k--)
    {
      try
       {
        i++;
        if (true)  //this condition will be removed
         {
           from = null;
           subject = null;
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mailItems[k];
           TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - mailitem.ReceivedTime;
           if (ts.TotalMinutes > minutesAged)
            {
              if (!((mailitem.SenderEmailAddress == null) || (mailitem.SenderEmailAddress == "")))
               {
                from = mailitem.SenderEmailAddress.ToString();
               }
              if (!((mailitem.Subject == null) || (mailitem.Subject == "")))
               {
                subject = mailitem.Subject;
               }
              await logFile.WriteLineAsync(i + ". From: " + from + "  - Subject: " + subject);
              mailitem.Move(testFolder);
            }
         }
       }
      catch (Exception e)
       {
        await logFile.WriteLineAsync("Exception caught: " + e.ToString());
       }
 }
 await logFile.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - End of Job.");
}
 catch (Exception e)
  {
   await logFile.WriteLineAsync("Exception caught: " + e.ToString());
  }
 logFile.Flush();
 logFile.Close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Outlook has an option to do that. Auto archive.

Comment: McNets, Thanks for your info.  I will explore it.

Comment: Mr. McNets, it seems that I won't be able to use the "Auto Archive" feature because it runs when Outlook is started.  My program will run in a Windows server that does not have Outloook nor users that will work on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Namespace.Logon` takes the name of an existing profile (as shown in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles), not an address of a mailbox.

Secondly, to open a folder from another user's mailbox, replace the `GetDefaultFolder` call with `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for your answer.  I will look for the profile of that email account, and will use the namespace methods that you indicated.  I will keep you posted.  I apreciatte your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't specify the profile name, it will use the default one. And if Outlook is already running, Namespace.Logon won't do anything.

Comment: Hello Dmitry.  I followed your advice.  I can get a recipient object and its recipient.Resolve(); methods returns true.  Then, I execute this instruction:

Comment: Dmitry, the second instruction is ``` inboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox); ```, this returns a collection of folders and most of its properties have errors. The count property of the folders contains error as well.  Question: Am I missing the act of login in to the mailbox?  Please help.

Comment: `GetSharedDefaultFolder` returns `MAPIFolder` object, not a collection of folders. Do you mean you cannot access child folders in the `MAPIFolder.Folders` collection?

Comment: Dmitry,  Now I am inside the inbox, however there is a login screen that asks for credentials.  Not doing it the mailitems object gets nothing. Do you know how I can skip that login screen?  the code is in the next comment:

Comment: this is the code: ```                recipient = outlookNameSpace.CreateRecipient("validEmailAddress@company.com");
                recipient.Resolve();
                if (recipient.Resolved)
                {
                    inboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                    outlookNameSpace.Logon("profile", "password", false, true);
                    mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;
                }  ```

Comment: What login screen? Do you mean security prompt? Or an actual user name/password prompt?

Comment: It is:  Windows Security /n  Microsoft Outlook /n Connecting to xxx.@yyy.com /n Password text box /n Remember my credentials checkbox /n More Choices link /n OK button Cancel Button.

Comment: Is Outlook running at that ime?

Comment: Good morning Dmitry. The program starts by killing any process named "OUTLOOK", I use the kill and the WaitForExit methods.  In effect it kills it. The new instance of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application interface is created with this instruction: Application OutLookApplication = null;  Login screen appears after this instruction is executed: recipient.Resolve();.  Thank you very much for the time that are spending to help me.

Comment: I don't think users would appreciate an app killing their Outlook, where they might have unsaved work. To kill Outlook (I still don't understand why you'd want to force that on users), all you need to do is call Application.Quit. After creating an instance of Outlook.Application, add code like `ns = Application.GetNamespace("Logon"); ns.Logon();`

Comment: There is a miss understanding.  This is a console application that will run on a server fully unattended.  I am killing it because I am writing the code otherwise the program will use my own inbox.  Thanks

Comment: Outlook Object Model cannot be used in any kind of unattended app, especially a service or an app launched from the Task Scheduler. EWS or Graph would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions don't make any sense due to the following statement:

> The program will run in a server on a frequency set in Windows task scheduler.

That is the key statement in your post because MS states the following for such scenarios:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with Exchange accounts you may consider using EWS instead, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information. In case of Office365 consider using the Graph API, see [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Comment: Eugene,  thank you very much for your comment.  I was not aware and did not research long enough the considerations for server-side automation of Office.  I will take the road of Exchange Web Services.  Best,